# error with my activity which cannot display it is layout

Tags: android

my app gets me error in QuestionActivity as it does not show activity_question.xml 
i think that the error will be in app_bar_question.xml

the app was working perfectly before i change the package name from example to funky

despite that the old version still works as needed and i checked if there are any difference between them but cannot detect any

logcat :-

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thing.quiz_10/com.thing.quiz_10.QuestionActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class fragment
  at com.thing.quiz_10.QuestionActivity.onCreate(QuestionActivity.java:90)
```

my question activty at line 90 :-

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(Common.selectedCourse.getName());
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

activity_question.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_question" />



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_question.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".QuestionActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_question" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_question.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_question">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/grid_answer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_question_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/grid_answer"
            android:text="0/30"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="20:00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable">

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: app_bar_question.xml is not well-formed XML.The start tag is  CoordinatorLayout, but the end tag is AppBarLayout. And you have an include tag outside of the root element.

Comment: add your content_question xml too

Comment: @HaiderSaleem
done

Comment: add your activity complete code, there's some mismatch error while inflating fragment.